# Loop to append several .dta files

Tags: loops, append, stata

I'm relatively new to stata and I need to append several .dta files together into one dataset.

I have a folder called 2015 and the files look like the following...

```
jan_2015.dta 
feb_2015.dta 
mar_2015.dta
```

... and so on till `dec_2015`.

I tried the following code:

```
cd C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Lender_List\Compiled\2015

local mylist jan_2015 feb_2015 mar_2015 apr_2015 may_2015 jun_2015 jul_2015 aug_2015 sep_2015 oct_2015 nov_2015 dec_2015

foreach filename of local mylist {
  use `var'_2015
  append using "jan_2015.dta"
}
```

but the output from stata said that `file _2015.dta not found`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to loop: `append` can take a list of files that you can get with `fs`:

```
ssc install fs
cd C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Lender_List\Compiled\2015
clear
fs *_2015.dta
append using `r(files)'
```

If you are still eager to loop over files by name for some reason:

```
cd C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\Lender_List\Compiled\2015
clear
foreach filename in `=lower("`c(Mons)'")' {
 append using "`filename'_2015.dta"
}
```

The main problem with your code is that the local macro lname is filename, but you dereference something called var, which evaluates to nothing, so Stata cannot find the file named _2015.dta and complains. The second problem is that your loop seems to try to open each month's file and append January's data to it. That does not sound like what you have in mind.

Comment: @nabilah Did this help?

Comment: Hi Dimitriy, This works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @nabilah Then please select it as the answer using the check mark on the left.